# Install Kotlin on ubuntu 21.04 Desktop(arm64)

Tags: kotlin

i have a raspberry pi 4 with ubuntu 21.04 Desktop and i want to install kotlin (I don't want to use snap).
Can anyone tell me how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest/officially supported way to get started is using IntelliJ IDEA Community. Take a look at [this guide](https://geektechstuff.com/2019/06/08/installing-intellij-ide-on-raspberry-pi-java-raspberry-pi/) for an in-depth explanation on RPi, without Snap. The Kotlin plugin comes bundled with the application, so it should be installed by this point. You can then create a new project, and IntelliJ will guide you on setting up a native (binary executable/shared library) or JVM (compatible with Java) project.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I want to use Kotlin from vs code. is there a way to install it without intelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @jack07Code It's possible to install without IntelliJ, but it's substantially more annoying. Also, VS Code doesn't have any good Kotlin language extensions, so syntax highlighting/code tooling won't be nearly as good as IntelliJ